# Weird shadows when changing the material of a model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When changing the color of my model I end up with strange shadows on my model:

[image: Original Model]

[image: Colored Model]

I tried different models already but had the same problem. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Code below:

```
   async foo() {

    let myMaterial = this.addMaterial(0x7CD254);

    const leafNodeIds = await this.getLeafNodes();

    this.setMaterial(leafNodeIds, myMaterial);

  }

  addMaterial(color) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: color
    });

    this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(
      this.guid(),
      material);

    return material;
  }

  static async setMaterial(dbId, material) {

    var fragIds = await this.getFragIds(dbId);

    fragIds.forEach((fragId) => {

      this.viewer.getFragmentList().setMaterial(
        fragId, material);
    });
  }
```

EDIT: A different angle, showing that these weird shadows also appear on the top

[image: top view]

Comment: Did you play with different light presets and also turning off the anti-aliasing from the appearance settings?

Comment: Hi Philippe, I tried most of the presets but this did not work :( How do you change the anti-aliasing though ?. The only thing related to anti-aliasing that I could find in the documentation of the viewer was the function: setQualityLevel(bool,bool) (turing it off here did not solve my problems with the shadowy material)

Comment: From the UI, the settings (gear icon, 3rd button on the 3rd toolbar, starting from the left on the above picture), then look in "appearance settings" and sorry the setting you need to turn OFF is "Ambient shadows", this is definitely the one causing this ugly effect. But on the API side it is controlled by  "viewer.setQualityLevel(bool,bool)"

Comment: Ahhh thanks Philippe, this did the trick :D

Comment: Cool ....... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shout out to Philippe Leefsma for finding the right solution.

You have to **turn off** the **Ambient shadows** option by either

- deselecting the option in the menu in the UI (gear icon)
- or by using the viewer.setQualityLevel(bool,bool) function in your code and setting the first argument to false

Answer (score 0):

why not change a new color....

`material.color=new THREE.Color(0,0,0);// like this`

forge's phongmaterial is not same as ThreeJS 
so shadows will be broken~~~